# Как заменить в списке 0 на NaN?

Tags: python, list, список, nan

Нахожу замену `NaN` на 0, а вот наоборот, не нахожу.

Как заменить заначения в списке на `Nan`?

```
[0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0]
```

Comment: Это обычный Python список или numpy.array или pandas.Series ?

Comment: list = [], обычный

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для обычного (`"vanilla Python"`) списка:

```
res = [x if x else float("nan") for x in lst]
```

Пример:

```
In [256]: lst = [0,1,0,2,0,0,3]

In [257]: res = [x if x else float("nan") for x in lst]

In [258]: res
Out[258]: [nan, 1, nan, 2, nan, nan, 3]
```